# Could not create the Java Virtual Machine on Ubuntu VPS with all the ram allocated to it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, java, vps

I'm trying to run a file on a vps with 384mb of ram, If I run the file with this command on terminal

```
java -jar server.jar
```

It just starts the process but with only 180mb approx allocated to it, I need to allocate all the ram avaiable, if not the server will end crashing. I run the command free -m and I get this output:

```
                 total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           384         58        325          6          0         44
-/+ buffers/cache:         14        369
Swap:           96          0         96
```

So I've tried lots of commands with different amounts of ram like those but no one worked, java could not create the java virtual machine:

```
java -Xms32M -Xmx256M -jar minecraft_server.jar
```

I tried putting the maximum ram, half and changing values but it gives error. Before I was running the same file on a 1GB vps and that command was working fine:

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar bukkit.jar
```

My java version is:

```
    java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

My OS is Ubuntu Server 12.04 x86
Hope you can help me, I'm stuck with the same problem two days

EDIT: Error messages with different amounts of ram

```
    root@vps-dot-me:~# java -Xms32M -Xmx384M -jar mine.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

root@vps-dot-me:~# java -server -Xms128M -Xmx256M -jar mine.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

    root@vps-dot-me:~# java -XX:MaxHeapSize=256m -jar mine.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Comment: So, what’s the error message?

Comment: Edited with error messages

Comment: Problem solved finally, I needed to allocate 128mb max with this command and it worked: java -server -Xms32M -Xmx128M -jar mine.jar

Answer (score 1):

Memory allocation may be too small. try incrementing it a bit at a time. If it fails on the smaller one try the next larger allocation.

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms128m -Xmx128m
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms256m -Xmx256m
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m
```

run this command after setting same:

```
java -jar yourJavaApp.jar
```

(you need to be within your app's directory).

Please note that you may try it "temporarily" by passing in as an option:

```
java -Xms128m -Xmx128m -jar yourJavaApp.jar
```

It fails because the JRE doesn't have enough memory allocated. Perhaps you're running too many open apps, low on memory, etc.